# Upsert Multiple Records with external ID with REST API

Tags: rest-api, contact, externalid

I am trying to update multiple contact records via the REST API that have an external Id `CustomField__c`.

Is there any way to do this?

I've tried using Workbench, hitting

(POST)   /services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Contact/CustomField__c

(PAYLOAD)

```
[{"LastName":"Jack",
  "CustomField__c":"0402236",
  "AssistantName":"Smith",
  "Languages__c":"0402236",
  "FirstName":"Jack"}]
```

But it returns back:

```
BAD_REQUEST
errorCode: BAD_REQUEST
message: CustomField__c is not an Id field.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with the endpoint you're trying to use; the method only allows updating a single record at a time, and uses the following syntax:

(PATCH) /services/data/41.0/sobjects/Contact/CustomField__c/ExtIdValue

If you want to upload multiple records at once, use the [Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) resource:

(POST) /services/data/41.0/composite

```
{
"compositeRequest" : [{
  "method" : "PATCH",
  "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/CustomField__c/ExtIdValue",
  "body" : { "LastName" : "Jack", ... }
  }, ...]
}
```

You do not specify the external Id in the body, as it is specified in the URL. If you need to upload a larger number of records, consider using SOAP, Bulk, etc APIs. You might also be interested in the [SObject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm) API, which is in the documentation. It allows up to 200 records per request, unlike the composite API's limit of 25 requests.